# Pattern synonym directionality

Tags: haskell

The two types are isomorphic, but there is a slight restriction to only **unidirectional** type synonym for `ZeroF` for which I am not sure there is a way out of.

```
data NatF x  = NatF { unNatF :: (forall u. Either u x) }
pattern ZeroF  <- NatF (Left _)
pattern SuccF n = NatF (Right n)

data PeanoF x =  ZeroFP | SuccFP x  -- isomorphe
```

Am I doing something wrong (beside the contrived example.. ) ?

Comment: What's with the quantification of `u`?  That's not typically useful.

Comment: The only bottom-free values of type `forall u. Either u x` are of the form `Right something`. In the other direction, `ZeroF` should be defined to evaluate to `NatF $ Left undefined`. (Why are you using that?)

Comment: I wanted to express the algebra F X =  1 + X but obviously that's Either () x..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having trouble because you've set up your assumptions wrong. `forall u. Either u x` is not isomorphic to your `PeanoF x`. The latter is isomorphic to `Either () x` (or just `Maybe x`); the former is isomorphic to `x`.

```
newtype NatF x = NatF (Maybe x)
pattern ZeroF = NatF Nothing
pattern SuccF n = NatF (Just n)
```